# chroot question

Tags: mount, chroot

I am wondering if there is anyone out there that can explain an error that happens when I try to use debootstrap.

```
sudo debootstrap --arch i386 wheezy /srv/chroot/wheezy http://http.debian.net/debian
mknod: `/srv/chroot/wheezy/test-dev-null': Operation not permitted
E: Cannot install into target '/srv/chroot/wheezy' mounted with noexec or nodev
```

Comment: The error message is fairly clear. "/srv/chroot/wheezy' mounted with noexec or nodev" . you would have to post mount information for a more exact answer. This may be closed as off topic as you are running Debian in a chroot and to a large extent, chroot is depreciated in favor of LXC, depending on your use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is self-explanatory: the filesystem that is mounted at (or that contains) `/srv/chroot/wheezy` has either the `noexec` or `nodev` mount flags. Try:

```
mount -o remount,rw,exec,dev /srv/chroot/wheezy
```

Answer (score 1):

When you mount the filesystem or the partition, you need to include the following arguments:

```
-o exec,dev
```